# Create Directory with for loop

Tags: r, csv

[image][image]I continue to run into invalid 'path' argument when running my new script. I have a list of States in a .csv I have import and I am writing a for loop to dir.create.

I have tried Multiple ways to write this but not working. I can successfully create a dir by simply writing dir.create("new"), however it does not create when I use my variable in a for loop.

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(tm)
library(stringi)
library(readr)

states = read.csv('C:/Users/mike/Desktop/Housing_Data/states/stateslist.csv', header = TRUE)

for(state in states){
  print(as.character(state))
  setwd('C:/Users/mike/Desktop/Housing_Data/states/')
  dir.create(paste0('C:/Users/mike/Desktop/Housing_Data/states/', state))
}
```

I expected the new directories to be created but running into path error

Comment: just `dir.create(state)` should be enough. And `setwd()` is not necessary inside the loop

Comment: tried that as well. I removed the setwd() as you recommended

Comment: would you please post the output of `states`

Comment: It is in a date frame named states: Header: states,Alabama,Alaska, etc. 50 obs. of 1 variable. Do I need to convert them to a character or string? not to sure

Comment: Please add the complete output to the original post. It's hard to debug without seeing exactly what you're giving as input for the path parameter.

Comment: added quick snips, is that ok?

Comment: It looks like in the for loop you have a capital "M" for "Mike", but elsewhere you have a lowercase "m". Could that be it?

Comment: I feel like the " " around the state is the issue

Comment: As a sanity check you could add a `print(paste0('C:/Users/mike/Desktop/Housing_Data/states/', state))` so you can inspect the paths it's generating

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199144/discussion-between-tyler-burleigh-and-mike-j).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over the column of your data frame in my example `states$state`, in yours data frame it should be `states$states`.
This works for me:

```
states <- data.frame(state = c("foo", "bar"))

setwd('C:/Users/mike/Desktop/Housing_Data/states/')
for(state in states$state){
  print(as.character(state))

  dir.create(state)
}
```

---

alternative: without `setwd()`

```
states <- data.frame(state = c("foo", "bar"))

for(state in states$state){

  print(as.character(state))

  dir.create(paste0('C:/Users/mike/Desktop/Housing_Data/states/', state))
}
```

Comment: Got it. Adding the $state into the for loop was the trick. Thanks!